# How do you do a double horizontal line on top and bottom of a div?

Tags: html, css

I don't understand how to do a double horizontal line on top and bottom of a div.

I am basically using this but it only gives me a single line on top and bottom

```
.test {
border-top: 1px double #333;
border-bottom: 1px double #333;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Actually, your [example](http://www.gregquinn.com/doubleborder.html) is correct, the problem was only in the width of the border as you have to increase it in order to see the double lines. therefore, just add `border-width: 5px;` to your css. :-)

Comment: Given that a pixel is the smallest unit of a display panel, how do you expect to have a one-pixel border that has two lines separated by a space? Logic alone suggests that a minimum border-width has to be three-pixels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increase the width of the border as illustrated in the following:

```
.test {
    border-bottom: 4px double #333;
    border-top: 4px double #999;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xnc5a1vp/)

Comment: This answer is clearly better, I've removed My answer.

Comment: I haven't learned internal or external CSS pages, only inline CSS. Could you rephrase it in inline format for me?